# Setting values for index Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of values: [false.csv](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/9dafe2177d0df436fb7f8a04fc4508d7)
I have index values as:

```
Time
2019.01.02 06:01:00
2019.01.02 06:09:00
2019.01.02 06:12:00
2019.01.02 06:19:00
2019.01.02 06:21:00
2019.01.02 06:26:00
2019.01.02 06:44:00
```

I want to set the values to zero for the above index which are in separate file. I tried to load the data but could not get the path to move forward.

here is the way I loaded data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("false.csv")
df1= pd.read_csv("set.csv")
```

Let me know how I can move forward.

Comment: sorry but i didnt understand the question. Can you add more details to "I want to set the values to zero for the above index which are in separate file."

Comment: You see the main dataset is the false.csv. I have collected the few indexes and want the values of those indexes in the main file as zero. If they are one then set to zero if there are zero still set to zero.

Comment: I edited in the dataset because that is what is usually expected around here. Please consider reverting your edit to show it. If you feel it is too long, than produces a shorter one that is a proper MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you load the `false` file make sure your index is by date:

```
df = pd.read_csv("false.csv",index_col=0)
df1= pd.read_csv("set.csv")
```

Next, just set what you need to 0:

```
df.loc[df1['Time']] = 0
```

`loc` matches indices, rather than titles.